# Image generated by Mapbox static image Url different from canvas on the DOM

Tags: javascript, canvas, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a website where I can customize a map, and them export it as a hi-def image so I can print it.

I generated the customizable map with mapboxgl API.

```js
const initMap = () => {
  const mapElement = document.getElementById('mapid');

  if (mapElement) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'mapid',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/ma-v/cjzv3hkp30svs1cp5xeexv54g',
      center: [5.380000, 43.300000],
      zoom: 11.5
    });
    let frame = document.querySelector('#mapid');
    frame.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="map-title"><div class="title-map"></div><div class="info-track"></div><div>')
  }
```

The user can customize the map (move localisation, zoom and change style layer basically). 
Once the user wants to print its map, I generate a [mapbox static image Url](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-images) with all the infos of the personnalisation of the user (currentZoom, currentCenter, styleLayer), and I apply to it dimensions of 914px x 1280px (maximum size possible with mapbox).

The problem is that the rendered image covers a much bigger area than the DOM map (see example links below). Indeed, both have the same center, the same zoom, but the url image is twice the dom image in terms of pixels. 
[Dom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRZa5.jpg) [Url image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqWPB.png)

What I'd like is to keep the same zoom scale (so the rendered map is the same), but have a larger size of image in terms of pixels so I can print it in good quality.
I've tried several ways but always end up with this same issue.

Thank you VERY much for your help. 
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody would be interested, I finally managed to solve this by changing the initial width and height of the map div to 914 x 1280, and then resizing the canvas after the downloading of the DOM.

```js
if (mapElement) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'mapid',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/ma-v/cjzv3hkp30svs1cp5xeexv54g',
      center: [5.380000, 43.300000],
      zoom: 11.5
    });
    mapElement.classList.toggle("small");
    const mapCanvas = document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-canvas');
    mapCanvas.style.width = "100%";
    mapCanvas.style.height = "100%";
```

```css
#mapid.small {
  width: 426px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

That way, the canvas "real" size is 914 x 1280, and yet it's displayed in a smaller div for the user.